# Fix Popup to lift up smoothly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, popup

I create a pop-up dialog box which lift up on left bottom while user scroll page.
You can see it live here- http://uposonghar.com/jobs/odesk/daniel/new/

My problem is it does not smoothly lift up first time, then it is ok. Anyone please suggest any idea to fix it. Need to make smoothly lift up.

My code

```
<div id="scrolltriggered" style="width: 310px; left: 10px; bottom: 10px;">
<div id="inscroll">
    <a href="#close" id="closebox">x</a><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank"><img src="images/buyersguide.png" alt="Free Resources" height="235" width="310">
     </a>
</div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript"> 
var stb = {
hascolsed: false,
cookieLife: 7,
triggerHeight: 30,
stbElement: ""
}; 
</script>
```

Javascript Code-

```
if (typeof stb === "undefined")
var stb = {};
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
jQuery("#closebox").click(function () {
    jQuery('#scrolltriggered').stop(true, true).animate({ 'bottom':'-210px' }, 700, function () {
        jQuery('#scrolltriggered').hide();
        stb.hascolsed = true;
        jQuery.cookie('nopopup', 'true', { expires: stb.cookieLife, path: '/' });
    });
    return false;
});

stb.windowheight = jQuery(window).height();
stb.totalheight = jQuery(document).height();
stb.boxOffset = '';
if (stb.stbElement != '') {
    stb.boxOffset = jQuery(stb.stbElement).offset().top;
}
jQuery(window).resize(function () {
    stb.windowheight = jQuery(window).height();
    stb.totalheight = jQuery(document).height();
});

jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
    stb.y = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
    stb.boxHeight = jQuery('#scrolltriggered').outerHeight();
    stb.scrolled = parseInt((stb.y + stb.windowheight) / stb.totalheight * 100);


    if (stb.showBox(stb.scrolled, stb.triggerHeight, stb.y) && jQuery('#scrolltriggered').is(":hidden") && stb.hascolsed != true) {
        jQuery('#scrolltriggered').show();
        jQuery('#scrolltriggered').stop(true, true).animate({ 'bottom':'10px' }, 700, function () {
        });
    }
    else if (!stb.showBox(stb.scrolled, stb.triggerHeight, stb.y) && jQuery('#scrolltriggered').is(":visible") && jQuery('#scrolltriggered:animated').length < 1) {
        jQuery('#scrolltriggered').stop(true, true).animate({ 'bottom':-stb.boxHeight }, 700, function () {
            jQuery('#scrolltriggered').hide();
        });
    }
});

jQuery('#stbContactForm').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    stb.data = jQuery('#stbContactForm').serialize();

    jQuery.ajax({
        url:stbAjax.ajaxurl,
        data:{
            action:'stb_form_process',
            stbNonce:stbAjax.stbNonce,
            data:stb.data
        },
        dataType:'html',
        type:'post'

    }).done(function (data) {
            jQuery('#stbMsgArea').html(data).show('fast');
        });

    return false;
});
});

(function(stb_helpers) {
stb_helpers.showBox = function(scrolled, triggerHeight, y) {
    if (stb.isMobile()) return false;
    if (stb.stbElement == '') {
        if (scrolled >= triggerHeight) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    else {
        if (stb.boxOffset < (stb.windowheight + y)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
};
stb_helpers.isMobile = function(){
    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)
        || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i)
        || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)
        || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)
        || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i)
        ) {
        return true;
    }
    else return false;
}
})(stb);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you need css changes, copy paste the following in your aspx

```
<div style="width: 310px; left: 10px; bottom: -225px; display: none;" id="scrolltriggered">
```

Hope it Helps

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is add the following line to your document ready as the First line

```
$("#scrolltriggered").css({bottom: -235});
```

This will make sure that the popup is scrolled to the bottom  by 235px. If you need it to scroll variably add the Elements height by using jquery selector.

See the Fiddle [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/LZnHm/)